En un codigo de arduino el bluetooth hc06 no recibe de forma correcta el texto enviado desde una app del telefono, ¿como lo puedo arreglar?
Disculpen, estoy tratando de que una palabra que envio a traves de esta app:

para que pueda recibirlo mi BLuetooth HC06 e imprimirlo tanto en el monitor serial, como en la pantalla de luces led P10:
mi codigo es:
#include <SPI.h>       
#include <DMD.h>    
#include <TimerOne.h>  
#include "Arial_black_16.h"
#include "Arial_Black_16_ISO_8859_1.h"
#include "Arial14.h"
#include "SystemFont5x7.h"
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define DISPLAYS_ACROSS 3 // Número de paneles P10 usados, de lado a lado.
#define DISPLAYS_DOWN 1
DMD dmd(DISPLAYS_ACROSS, DISPLAYS_DOWN);
SoftwareSerial bluetooth(2, 3); // Módulo Bluetooth
char Text[50]; // Array para almacenar el texto
bool bluetoothConnected = false; // Variable para verificar la conexión Bluetooth

void ScanDMD() { 
  dmd.scanDisplayBySPI();
}

void setup(void) {
  
  Timer1.initialize(1000);          
  Timer1.attachInterrupt(ScanDMD);   
  dmd.clearScreen(true);   
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // Inicialización del Bluetooth
  bluetooth.begin(9600);  // Módulo Bluetooth
  bluetooth.setTimeout(1000);
  
  // Mensaje inicial en el puerto serie
  Serial.println("Esperando conexión Bluetooth...");
}

void loop(void) {
  if (bluetooth.available() > 0) {
    // Leer el texto desde el puerto serie hasta el salto de línea
   String inputText = bluetooth.readStringUntil('\n'); 

    inputText.toCharArray(Text, sizeof(Text)); // Convertir String a char array

    // Marcar la conexión Bluetooth después de recibir el primer mensaje
    if (!bluetoothConnected) {
      bluetoothConnected = true;
      Serial.println("Conexión Bluetooth establecida.");
    }
    
    // Asegúrate de que solo se envían caracteres ASCII válidos
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(Text); i++) {
      if (Text[i] < 0 || Text[i] > 127) {
        Text[i] = '?'; // Reemplaza caracteres no válidos con '?'
      }
    }
    
    // Mostrar el texto recibido en el DMD
    dmd.selectFont(Arial_Black_16_ISO_8859_1);
    dmd.drawMarquee(Text, strlen(Text), (32 * DISPLAYS_ACROSS) - 1, 0);
    
    // Enviar el texto al módulo Bluetooth
    bluetooth.println(Text); // Envía el texto recibido al Bluetooth
    Serial.println("Texto enviado: " + inputText); // Imprime el texto recibido

    long start = millis();
    long timer = start;
    boolean ret = false;
    int interval = 10;

    while (!ret) {
      if ((timer + interval) < millis()) {
        ret = dmd.stepMarquee(-1, 0);
        timer = millis();
      }
    }
  }
}

y el resultado que me da en el monitor serial al enviar un dato es este:

¿que esta mal o que puedo cambiar?.................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
........................................
............................................
........................................
.

me quedó asi:
  #include <SPI.h>       
#include <DMD2.h>
#include "Arial_black_16.h"
#include "Arial14.h"
#include "SystemFont5x7.h"
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define DISPLAYS_ACROSS 3 // Número de paneles P10 usados, de lado a lado.
#define DISPLAYS_DOWN 1
SoftDMD dmd(DISPLAYS_ACROSS, DISPLAYS_DOWN);  // Inicializar objeto DMD

SoftwareSerial BT(2, 3);

char palabra[1000];  // Buffer de tamaño 100 para almacenar la palabra


void setup() {
  BT.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("OK, LISTO!");
 
  // Configurar el temporizador para actualizar el panel
   dmd.setBrightness(255);
  dmd.selectFont(Arial_Black_16);
  dmd.begin();
}


void loop() {
  if (BT.available()) {
       int len = BT.readBytesUntil('\n', palabra, sizeof(palabra) - 1);  // Leer hasta un salto de línea

        Serial.println(palabra);  // Mostrar la palabra en el monitor serial
  delay(1000);
   
  }
  
}

si elimino su inicialización, funciona bien pero necesito que se muestre en el panel led, alguna sugerencia?

Cómo estás enviando el texto? Por cierto, no necesitas convertir el string en un char array, la clase String posee una sobrecarga para el operador [], una función length y c_str para poder obtener un puntero a un string de C.

Hola, fuí simplificando el codigo para ver en el serial cuando sucede el problema me di cuenta que como quiero que se reproduzca en la matriz led p10 es necesario incializar el DMD.begin(), el caso esque este produce que no se lea bien el dato, pero no se como arreglarlo
